# how to pass an array values to html?

Tags: angular

I have an array create in javascript page:

```
for (let i=0; i<12; i++){
  var M = Month[M].valueOf();
  TodayMonth.push(M);
}
```

How to pass the "TodayMonth" to HTML ?
which become `<td>TodayMonth</td>`

I tried `<td>{{TodayMonth}}</td>` --> fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the above logic works,

Since TodayMonth is an array, you can use a ngFor to display the array value

for example

```
<p *ngFor = 'let month of TodayMonth'> 
{{month}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should display each month.

```html
<div *ngFor="let month of TodayMonth">
   {{month}}
</div>
```